# How do i get this Jquery smooth-scroll to work?

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

I have found a smooth-scrolling Jquery file written by this guy Karl Swedberg. The link is here: https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-smooth-scroll.
What i wanted is to make my navigation icon smooth-scroll to the anchor point once clicked.
My Html code for navigation bar is here:

```
<div class="nav">           
    <ul>
        <li class="icon"><a href="#info"><img src="./Img/info-64.png" alt="info-icon"></a></li>
        <li class="icon"><a href="#education"><img src="./Img/Icon-edu.png" alt="info-icon"></a></li>
        <li class="icon"><a href="#employment"><img src="./Img/Icon-employment.png" alt="info-icon"></a></li>
        <li class="icon"><a href="#skill"><img src="./Img/Icon-skills.png" alt="info-icon"></a></li>
        <li class="icon"><a href="#achievement"><img src="./Img/Icon-achiev.png" alt="info-icon"></a></li>
        <li class="icon"><a href="#"><img src="./Img/photo-64.png" alt="info-icon"></a></li>
        <li class="icon"><a href="#personality"><img src="./Img/Icon-personality.png" alt="info-icon"></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

It is a vertical navigation bar with many icons instead of text.
The Jquery file is quite complicated for my current understanding, and i wouldn't be able to produce something more specific at this point yet. So your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using built in jquery animation would probably be easier. This page outline how to do this quite easily;

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

the code from there is this;

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

to use it add an anchor with href the same as the element you want to scroll to. e.g.

```
<a href="#one">link to div 1</a>
<div id="one"></div>
```